# Four integers in four bytes?

Tags: java, integer, byte, stanag

I wonder if I could ask for some advice regarding some work I'm currently doing.

I am working from a STANAG document which quotes the following:

> ID numbers shall be formed as 4-byte numbers. The first (most significant) byte shall be the standard NATO country code for the object in question.  Valid country codes shall range from 0 to 99 decimal... Country code 255 (hexadecimal FF) shall be reserved.

It then goes on to detail the three other bytes. In the specification, the ID is given the type Integer 4, where Integer n is a signed integer and n is 1,2, or 4 bytes.

My question, and I acknowledge this could be considered an ignorant question and I apologise, is that an integer is, as we know, 32 bits/4 bytes. How can "the first byte" be, for example, 99, when 99 is an integer?

I would greatly appreciate any clarification here.

Comment: How's 4586 treating you?

Comment: Wow I thought I was the only one in the world doing 4586!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An integer is normally 4 bytes.  But if you store a small number like 99, the other three bytes store 8x 0-value bits.  The spec is asking for you to use one integer storage (4-bytes) to store 4 different smaller numbers within its bytes.

The easiest way is probably to use a toInt function on an array of 4 bytes, e.g. *(there is no byte[] length checking nor is this function tested - it is illustrative only)*

```
public static final int toInt(byte[] b) 
{
    int l = 0;
    l |= b[0] & 0xFF;
    l <<= 8;
    l |= b[1] & 0xFF;
    l <<= 8;
    l |= b[2] & 0xFF;
    l <<= 8;
    l |= b[3] & 0xFF;
    return l;
}

byte[] bytes = new byte[] {99, 4, 9, 0};
int i = toInt(bytes, 0);
```

32-bits of an int

```
11110101   00000100   00001001   00000000
^byte      ^byte      ^byte      ^byte
```

Each block of 8 bits in the int is enough to "encode"/"store" a smaller number.  So an `int` can be used to mash together 4 smaller numbers.

Comment: Ah..I beleive I've misinterpreted the "Integer 4" part of the specification - as you and T.J. say, it must mean it as being an integer number rather than an integer type. I was looking at it with my brain in programming mode, it suddenly makes a lot more sense! Thank you very much for the code, that sounds like exactly what I'm after, though I won't require the toInt function as I beleive it's to be used as a byte array anyway. Thank you very much to you both, you've just cleared up what's been bugging me all morning!

Comment: As a followup question, would the same work with a double or characters? So instead of a double "51.304215" or a String "T-321", a byte array?

Comment: You can always coerce and bit shift into any storage.. since they end up as bytes.

Comment: What's the "toInt" function.  Where does it come from?

Answer (score 3):

"99" is an integer number mathematically, but not necessarily an `Integer` or `int` from the Java perspective. The value 99 can be held by a `short`, for instance (which is short for "short integer"), which is a 16-bit data type, or in a `byte`, which is an 8-bit data type.

So basically, you'll want to look at their ID thing as a series of four `byte` values. Beware that Java's `byte` type is signed.

Comment: Same comment as with cyberkiwi, if I could I would give two best answers, but thank you very much to you both, your explanations were exceptionally helpful.

Answer (score 1):

An integer (outside computing) just means any value without a decimal which includes 2, 99, -5, 34134, 427391471244211, etc.
In computing terms, an integer is (traditionally) a 32-bit number that can contains any value that will fit in it.
Each byte (8 bits) of that (computing) integer value is also an individual (numerical) integer between 0 and 255.